# Matlab class constructor calling a method for initialization

Tags: matlab, constructor

In a class constructor, if I call another method to initialize some property, why that property not changed?

Example code:

```
classdef Test
    properties
        prop    
    end 

    methods
        function obj = Test()
            obj.init(); 
        end     
        function init(obj)
            obj.prop = 1;
        end     
    end 
end
```

Then by executing `A = Test();` I got `A.prop = []`.

Comment: Note that you should only attempt this if the method is `Sealed` or has `Access = private`. Calling a virtual method (one that can be overridden) from a constructor is dangerous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Handle class

```
classdef Test < handle
```

This will apply methods to the **referenced** object.

### Value class

You have to return the modified object:

```
function obj = Test()
    obj.init();
end
```

should be

```
function obj = Test()
    obj = obj.init();
end
```

However, your `init()` is also not returning the modified object to the caller:

```
function init(obj)
    obj.prop = 1;
end
```

which should be

```
function obj = init(obj)
    obj.prop = 1;
end
```

### See also [comparing handle and value classes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).